# Java- gathering versions from pom with ArtifactVersionCollector

Tags: java, maven, versioning, git-submodules

I have an application with submodules in java configured in IntellIJ (java ones are unnamed).

Each submodule has its own pom in his base folder (compile works fine).

My goal is to have this function working for each submodule

```
import de.westemeyer.version.service.ArtifactVersionCollector;

class Main {
static String getVersion(){

String modname = "Main";
return modname + ":" + ArtifactVersionCollector.findArtifact("com.dds.project",modname);
}

public static void main(String[] argv){

    for(var v : artifactVersionCollector.collectArtifacts().toArray()){
            sLogger.error( "{}", v );
        }
}
}

class Prj2 {
static String getVersion(){

String modname = "prj2";
return modname + ":" + ArtifactVersionCollector.findArtifact("com.dds.project",modname);
}
}


class Prj3 {
static String getVersion(){

String modname = "prj3";
return modname + ":" + ArtifactVersionCollector.findArtifact("com.dds.project",modname);
}
}
```

Right now I can get the version if I run the application from IJ (As a Java app) but if I run it from the jar (also from IJ) I got only the version of a single component

Note: to make the jar I use `mvn clean package` and I run it with the same work-directory as the IJ run configuration.

```
base  
|  
 - prj1  
 --src  
 --- Main.java  
 --pom.xml  (Main:V1)  
 - prj2   
 --src  
 --- File2.java
 --pom.xml  (prj2:V2)  
 - prj3  
 --src  
 --- File3.java
 --pom.xml  (prj3:V3)  
- pom.xml (base:va) <== this one contains the modules section
```

Right now If I run the call above in Main.java I get the version of Prj3 (prj3:v3)

Comment: did you read the docs? _All "participating" jar files can contribute their own version by supplying their own implementation of the ArtifactVersionService._ So you probably have to do more than just read other modules versions?

Comment: First do you have really your source files `File3.java` in `src` directory and not in `src/main/java/<package>`?